# Unable to find files after setting path in vim

Tags: path

I open vim with `vim -u NONE <filename>`, so this ensures that the error is not due to vimrc or plugins. I use `checkpath!` to dump all files which are present in the path.

```
:set path?
path=.,/usr/include,,,~/main

:checkpath!
No files included

:set path=~/main/**
path=~/main/**

:checkpath!
No files included
```

```bash
$ ls -lR ~/main | wc -l
459590
```

Any suggestions to find why vim can't find the files in the path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you’ve misunderstood `'path'`. The path option determines which directories are searched for included files.

But what files are included are determined by the options `include`, `suffixesadd`, and `includeexpr`. These are used in combination to detect that the current file includes/imports some other filename; then that filename is searched for in the directories of path.

The `:find` command works directly based on path, but `:isearch`, related commands, and `:checkpath` require the include options to be set appropriately, and additionally they work based on what’s included in the current file.